# 'Since' or 'As a result'

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, conjunctions, exam-questions

I have one exercise to do for my English lesson.

> "As a result / Since all the seats on the train were taken, we had to
>   stand"

Which option should I choose?

I have found that I have to put comma after 'As a result'. The comma isn't there. Does it mean that I have to go with 'Since'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't substitute directly between those - they go in different places in the sentence.

> Since all the seats on the train were taken, we had to stand.
>
> All the seats on the train were taken; as a result, we had to stand.

Alternates include

> Because all the seats on the train were taken, we had to stand.
>
> All the seats on the train were taken; therefore, we had to stand.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to choose between these two *cause & effect* words, then I would choose "**since**", because if I omit the word since and use "as a result", then the sentence is not logical and lacks some *conjunction*.

> "As a result [*absent part*] all the seats on the train were taken, we
>   had to stand"

It could be a normal option only if some other words would be inserted there, for instance:

> "As a result [*of the fact that*] all the seats on the train were
>   taken, we had to stand"

---

Then, in conclusion the only one correct option in your question is:

> "**Since** all the seats on the train were taken, we had to stand"

Answer (score 0):

When you have to make a choice between different subordinate clauses, always try to find the main clause (*we had to stand*) and ask a question which will help you recognize the type of the clause (why?).So the clause should explain the reason. Then it's easy to find the proper clause

> *Since all the seats on the train were taken*, we had to stand

The other one doesn't work here, because it shows the result.